# ubuntu 20.04, when shutting down Ubuntu restores tabs

Tags: 20.04, firefox, shutdown

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and when I shut down (with Firefox still opened) when I turn it on, Ubuntu restores all the some tabs. Is this the usual behavior? I am expecting after shutdown when I open Firefox to have a clean/new window.

Comment: I Noticed the same. So it should be normal behavior.  you can look into Firefox settings for customizing the behavior in Question.

Comment: I agree, but there is no such setting, or at least I can't find it...

Comment: Isn't it at the very top of the Preferences page: "Restore previous session"?

Comment: Yep, I have that unchecked but still does the same.

Comment: My guess is that it's mistaking my shutdown (with firefox open) with a crash...

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the restore function after a crash, just enter `about:config` in Firefox address bar and enter `browser.sessionstore.resume_from_crash`. I assume it is set to `true`, by setting it to `false` your problem should be solved.

In case of a real crash of your PC or Firefox you do no longer have the option to restore your tabs!

Comment: It makes sense, but why do I have to do this? I am shutting down, it's not an event of a crash. I would like to be able to resume from crash at the same time not resume when I shut down myself.